# Auto-Update app

Tags: android, google-play, auto-update

Can someone explain when/how is decided to auto-update an app from Google Play. I have an app published on Google Play and updated to a newer version. It seems like it was already accepted and everything looks ok. I selected on my device to auto-update apps from Google Play, but it seems like it does not want to make it.
How long should I wait to get this notification of auto-updating app? Does it(my app) have to be opened (or would it influence in some way)?

Comment: checkout this http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/app-permissions-work-care-android/

Comment: @User_2013 I read that, but my app does not require any additional permissions. Although I can see there are many more waiting for manual update on my device (apps like Android Chrome, and others).

Comment: Depending on country and network it make take up to 48 hours.